# Can travelling salesman be translated into a SAT problem?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization, np-complete, network, satisfiability

I read that all NP-complete problems can be translated into one another.

I can't see how the travelling salesman problem which involves distances which are real numbers can be translated into a boolean satisfaction problem? Do you have to limit it to integer distances?

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This would be an apporpiate question for the CS theory group.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's firmly within the realm of computer science rather than mathematics.

Comment: I always thought algorithms was part of maths. But times have changed I see.

Comment: See for example: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/how-are-real-numbers-specified-in-computation

Comment: You will probably get a better answer on the CS theory stack exchange. The problem is often expressed in terms of the **costs** of the trips (in some notional currency unit), and those costs will be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what all the comments are talking about, this is definitely a question in Mathematics. To answer your question, we note that real numbers aren't actually encodable by Turing Machines (if they're infinitely long), so the problem of TSP over arbitrary real numbers is not really applicable (how would you even express the input?). Over rational numbers (or any other countable subset of real numbers that is closed under addition) it can still be done since they're countable, so they can be encoded in similar ways as integers.

Also if you look at Cook's proof that SAT is NP-Complete, you'll see that he uses a reduction from the non-deterministic polynomial time turing machine that solves an NP problem, so the structure of the problem isn't really relevant.

Comment: "the problem of the travelling salesman problem over arbitrary real numbers is not really applicable" yes it is, $c_{i,j}$ the cost of travelling from one city to another can take irrational values, like $\sqrt 2$ i.e. the distance in the usual metric.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my answer.